# Difficultly importing GeoTiff format

Tags: import, geographics

I downloaded Earth data from [here](http://api.globalsolaratlas.info/download/World/World_DIF_GISdata_LTAy_AvgDailyTotals_GlobalSolarAtlas-v2_GEOTIFF.zip). It is a `GeoTiff` file, which is a map of solar radiation falling on earth.

[image]

Mathematica claims to [import](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/GeoTIFF.html) `GeoTiff` files. However, when I import,

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
files = FileNames["*", "./diffuse/"][[1]]
diffuse = Import[files, {"GeoTIFF", "Image"}]
```

The output is an error:

```
LinkObject::linkd: Unable to communicate with closed link LinkObject['/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Converters/Binaries/MacOSX-x86-64/GDAL.exe',6300,8].
Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as GeoTIFF format.
```

I can get the file to open using other GIS programs such as QGIS. So it does seem to be a Mathematica issue. Any ideas? It is an error which I have not encountered before.

Comment: My system (MMA 12 on Win10-64) does the same thing. The GDAL.exe file can be found where that path points, but trying to execute it manually brings up an error: "The code execution cannot proceed because ML64i4.dll was not found." This seems like a problem with MathLink. I do have copies of that DLL elsewhere in there, and copying one copy into that folder allows GDAL.EXE to execute, but unfortunately I do not know MathLink structures well enough to go any further.

Comment: Bug reported. I've been told there is no current workaround.

Comment: Now imports! - But all as NaN'

Comment: That's very unfortunate. Have you confirmed it with a known good file that can be imported correctly by another program? I think the only recourse is to report the bug again.

Comment: Conversion to https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/USGSDEM.html using 'gdal_translate -of USGSDEM DNI.tif output.dem' is an acceptable workaround for me.

Comment: That's great to hear. I recommend that you expand your comment into a self-answer with a few more details for the next person in the same predicament!